# wpa_supplicant: try connecting to wifi without password

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa, wpa-cli

when using wpa_supplicant and trying to connect to a wifi having a proper password the common approach would look somehow like that

```
add_network
set_network 0 ssid "myssid"
set_network 0 psk "mypassword"
enable_network 0
reassociate
```

where in case of failure I would receive those events

```
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED
CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED
```

whereas in case of success I would receive

```
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED
```

When now using no password, where the common approach, as I read would be

```
add_network
set_network 0 ssid "myssid"
set_network key_mgmt NONE
enable_network 0
reassociate
```

I don't receive any of the before mentioned events nor any other giving any hint about the status. I have not tested it when actually trying to connect to an unsecure password but what bothers me even more is that I don't get any WRONG_KEY information when trying to connect to a secured wifi. Is there any way to cope that?